# WPF GifBitmapDecoder Uri Relative Path Issue

Tags: wpf, image, path, uri, animated-gif

I am trying to set the uriString of a Uri object to a relative path for use in a GifBitmapDecoder.

At runtime i get the following error:

> `Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.`

My relative path follows the following format:

> `/TestApplication;component/Images/Busy.gif`

If i use the absolute path to the image, all works perfectly!

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx

I was missing the following: **pack://application:,,,** infront of my relative path.

Comment: The link isn't broken, it just defaults to the newest version of .NET. Try .NET 3.5 instead.